# How to remove the button pragmatically with tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, tags, addsubview, nsindexpath

I am adding button subView to each row I click. I am trying to remove the button subView every time once I click on different row and add button subview to the other row I click.

Where would be my issue? It is adding subView to each row without removing any of them.

```
if (sender.tag == 212)
  {
    myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    //Debug shows that every-time myButton&myButton2 hasn't tag??

    if (myButton2.tag != 0  && myButton.tag != 0)
    {
        [myButton removeFromSuperview];
        [myButton2 removeFromSuperview];
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = (id)sender.superview.superview.superview;

    CGPoint center= sender.center;
    CGPoint rootViewPoint = [sender.superview convertPoint:center toView:commonTable.table];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [commonTable.table indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootViewPoint];

    itemdata1 = [itemList objectAtIndex:indexPath1.row];

    if (closeManager) [closeManager release];

    CGFloat __y = commonTable.y + commonTable.table.y - commonTable.table.contentOffset.y + cell.height*indexPath1.row + sender.y;
    CGFloat __x = commonTable.x + commonTable.table.x + sender.x;
    CGRect layerBox1 = CGRectMake(618, __y, 90, sender.height+3);
    CGRect layerBox2 = CGRectMake(888, __y, 94, sender.height+3);

    NSLog(@"%f and %f", __x, __y);

    myButton.frame = layerBox1;
    [[myButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    myButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(func1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    myButton2.frame = layerBox2;
    [[myButton2 layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    [myButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(func2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    myButton2.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    [self addSubview:myButton];
    [self addSubview:myButton2];

    myButton.tag = myButton2.tag = 666;

}
```

Edited for Bhumeshwer katre:

```
    if (myButton&&myButton2)
    {
        [myButton removeFromSuperview];
        [myButton2 removeFromSuperview];
    }

    //Other variables 

    if(!myButton){
        myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        myButton.frame = layerBox1;
        [[myButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
        myButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(func1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        myButton.tag = 666;
        [self addSubview:myButton];
    }
```

Comment: What exactly you want? And what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre I am adding subView on the row I click. I just want to remove that subView when I click on other row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't create each time your button like this

Here you are creating each time new instance of UIButton

```
myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

And you are doing this

```
    //Debug shows that every-time myButton&myButton2 hasn't tag??
        if (myButton2.tag != 0  && myButton.tag != 0)
        {
            [myButton removeFromSuperview];
            [myButton2 removeFromSuperview];
        }
   //It will just remove new instance of UIButton and no more your UIButton will be there on UIView.
```

try like this

```
    if(!myButton){
        myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    }
    if(!myButton2) {
        myButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    }

//Don't remove your button just change frame
```

if you still want to remove buttons then first remove

```
   [myButton removeFromSuperview];
   [myButton2 removeFromSuperview];

 //then create new instance of button
```

Comment: Now I have tried `if(!myButton)` and I have removed the `removeFromSuperview`. It in not printing if I click on the other row.

Comment: where exactly you are addiing UIButton.  Try to debug code and see what wrong with UIButton objects.

Comment: I have debugged and it is showing me that I still have the button after I remove it from subview.

Comment: If you are removing UIButton from superview then make it nil also. Otherwise write change frame and add to superview outside of this `if(!myButton)` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding tags to buttons **before** adding them to subview.

So this:

```
    [self addSubview:myButton];
[self addSubview:myButton2];

myButton.tag = myButton2.tag = 666;
```

should become like this:

```
myButton.tag = myButton2.tag = 666;

[self addSubview:myButton];
[self addSubview:myButton2];
```

Regards,

hris.to

Answer (score 0):

If you use tableview cell, Use this following cases,

1) Set tag to button while creating tableViewCell.

2) Hide that button by `cell.yourButton.hidden = YES`

3) When you click on row, just note down that indexPath as `self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

4) Now reload your tableView. Just add one condition in `cellForRowAtIndexpath:` as below.

```
if (indexPath.row == self.selectedIndexPath.row)
{
   cell.yourButton.hidden = NO;
}
else 
   cell.yourButton.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: I am not using `cell` :(

Comment: Mani what if there are 50+ cells, memory would increase. Please good some good solution

Comment: @RavirajJadeja How would memory get increase even 10,000 cells? Only visible cells are remain in memory that is tableViewCell stack. Here nothing is wrong about memory. If see anything wrong, explain in detail. It will help to visitios..

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subView) { // instead of self.view you can use your main view
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && view.tag == ?) {
            UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)view;
            [btn removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to set tag your buttons first,because default tag of every UIControl is 0;